# Is it possible to breed monsters?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was building a monster zoo and i thought a baby spider would be adorable. Am I able to breed (have baby) monsters?

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot breed any hostile mobs or neutral mobs (excluding wolves).

You can breed these mobs:

- [Chickens](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chicken)
- [Cows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cow)
- [Horses](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse)
- [Ocelots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot)
- [Wolves](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf)
- [Pigs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pig)
- [Sheep](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep)
- [Mooshrooms](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mooshroom)
- [Villagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager)

I recommend you read the "[Breeding](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding)" page on the wiki, it has information on everything you need to know about breeding.

**I also recommend you bookmark the [official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki), it has the answer to almost every question you have to ask about Minecraft.**